# El nombre de columna no válida usando SQL Server y CakePHP

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

Ésta es mi petición, pero cuando llega al `where` me dice que el nombre de columna `"2020-02-01"` no es válida:

```
 <?php
 $pedidos = $this->PedidosVentas->find("all",
            ['contain'=>['Centros','TipoArticulos','Clientes2']])
            ->where(['PedidosVentas.fecha BETWEEN "2020-02-01" and "2020-02-29"'])
            ->order(['Centros.id'=>'ASC','TipoComidas.id'=>'ASC','TipoArticulos.id'=>'ASC'])->toArray();
```

No sé qué puede fallar para que me dé ese error, porque mi columna es `fecha` y no la fecha por la que filtro.

Comment: `TipoComidas` no las tienes en `contain`, por lo que no puedes hacer referencia a esa tabla en `TipoComidas.id`. ¿Podrías compartir el mensaje de error completo y exacto? Gracias.

Comment: Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]El nombre de columna '2020-02-01' no es válido. Ese es el error, lo de TipoComidas tenias razón lo quite, pero sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Vale, el problema parece que es que estás usando comillas dobles, cuando en SQL las cadenas (tanto en MySQL como en SQL Server) van con comillas simples. Prueba a cambiar esto: `where(['PedidosVentas.fecha BETWEEN \'2020-02-01\' AND \'2020-02-29\''])`

Comment: ¿Te funcionó con ese cambio?

Comment: Si , era ese el error

Comment: Si quieres, redacta una respuesta tú mismo explicando los cambios que hiciste, márcala como respuesta correcta y yo mismo te doy el primer +1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final lo solucione con el cambio de introducir las fechas en el BETWEEN.

```
$pedidos = $this->PedidosVentas->find("all",
    ['contain'=>['Centros','TipoArticulos','Clientes2']])
    ->where(['PedidosVentas.fecha BETWEEN \'2020-05-01\' and \'2020-05-29\''])
    ->order(['Centros.id'=>'ASC','TipoArticulos.id'=>'ASC'])->toArray();
```

Y ademas quitar la relación de TipoComidas que no la utilizaba

Answer (score 0):

Cake PHP no es SQL (al menos no lo que le introduces), y es poco probable que te deje usar todas las estructuras o comparadores de SQL.

Lo más sencillo es que uses 2 condiciones

```
<?php
 $pedidos = $this->PedidosVentas->find("all",
            ['contain'=>['Centros','TipoArticulos','Clientes2']])
            ->where(['PedidosVentas.fecha >= "2020-02-01"', 'PedidosVentas.fecha <= "2020-02-29"])
            ->order(['Centros.id'=>'ASC','TipoComidas.id'=>'ASC','TipoArticulos.id'=>'ASC'])->toArray();
```

Comment: Debo disentir, pero en el `WHERE` se pueden usar restricciones SQL normales como `BETWEEN`. Esta respuesta no le valdría al OP porque le falta una cosa muy importante (y el problema real): usar comillas simples en la fecha en vez de dobles.